# ChoETL.NACHA FileHeader is not including the File Creation Date

Tags: c#, choetl

I have upgraded my windows service to use ChoETL.Dll version 1.2.1.55 and ChoETL.NACHA version 1.0.2.3.  The NACHA file generated does not include the FileCreation date, which throws the file off as it should have a constant record length.  I have tried setting the file header file creation date, even though it defaults to today, but that did not help.

Comment: there was some dependency issue with ChoETL.NACHA 1.0.2.3 package. Fix the issue, released v1.0.2.6. Download and give it try. Let me know.

Comment: Sample working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wzcFUR